# How to customize wordpress sidebar widget

Tags: widgets, css, register-sidebar

**This is how i registered my sidebar:**

```
register_sidebar(array(
        'name' => 'Post Sidebar',
        'before_widget' => '<div class="widgetdiv"><div id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
        'after_widget' => '</div></div>',
        'before_title' => '<div class="titlediv">',
        'after_title' => '</div>',
    ));
```

**The problem I have:**

Title div wrapped inside widgetdiv. The above code output like this.

```
<div class="widgetdiv">
<div class="titlediv">My title
</div>
</div>
```

**My requirement:**

```
<div class="titlediv">My title
</div>
<div class="widgetdiv">
</div>
```

I mean titlediv should be outside widgetdiv

Can anyone give me good solution?. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
register_sidebar(array(
        'name' => 'Post Sidebar',
        'before_widget' => '<div id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
        'after_widget' => '</div></div>',
        'before_title' => '<div class="titlediv">',
        'after_title' => '</div><div class="widgetdiv">',
    ));
```

You will have a wrapper div, then your title div and then your widgetdiv.

Comment: Trust me dude. You are awesomeeeee.... Thankyou very much.